# Need to redirect missing URLs to new host

Tags: html, .htaccess, url, redirect, uri

I'm moving a blog from one site to another and repurposing the original site. I want to maintain all existing links that point to the site and hopefully maintain SEO page ranking.

Old URL: http://www.companyabc.com/2010/04/test.html

New URL: http://blog.companyabc.com/2010/04/test.html

The way I'd like to do it is to use a custom 404 error page on www.companyabc.com like this:

```
<html><meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://blog.companyabc.com/%1"></html>
```

where **%1** is the original URI (/2010/04/test.html), but I don't know if that's possible.

Another option is to use an .htaccess file that redirects if the URL is not found, but I haven't gotten that to work either. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong in the rewrite condition:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ https://blog.companyabc.com/$1.html [R=301,L]
```

Any suggestions? Thanks for the help.

Comment: To do this via the 404 error document, that one would have to actually be a script (like PHP), so that you can check what URL was actually requested, and insert it dynamically. (Although in that case, you could have the script issue a Location header directly, instead of generating a response with a meta refresh.)

Comment: Why is your .htaccess attempt using the `!-l` flag? // That RewriteRule pattern should probably be made a bit more specific - right now, you would redirect _every_ request ending in `.html` with that, but if I requested just `http://www.companyabc.com/foobar.html`, that should probably give me a 404 under that domain, and not redirect elsewhere, right? So I would probably have that pattern match the `YYYY/MM/` prefix of your blog entry URL structure.

Comment: I'm 100% new to .htaccess so I'm trying examples I've seen in Google. What condition would I use to test if a URL exists on www.companyabc.com and rewrite to blog.companyabc.com if it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using the following .htaccess configuration:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://blog.companyabc.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I never tried the REQUEST_FILENAME value because I mistakenly thought it only applied to files that can be downloaded from the website. I didn't realize it also applies to the .html files in the blog.

With this solution all URLs that don't exist at www.companyabc.com will be redirected to blog.companyabc.com instead of showing a 404 error page, which is what I'm looking for.